# iPad development- copying the result

Tags: ipad

I am fresh to the iPad app development. Now I am developing a calculator. And I want copy my result of the calculation to  textEdit or to my mail which is outside the application. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the text is selectable users should be able to copy and paste the information using the iOS clipboard themselves, this is probably the easiest option if you don't have a specific other application for them to copy to.

Comment: can you please explain it more?

Comment: new (post 3.0 I think) versions of iOS have a built in copy paste clipboard. as long as your result is displayed as text (not an image or similar) users can select the text and use the internal copy and paste methods into any other application

Comment: if it is textfield i can copy and paste to any application. But if it is a label then how can i copy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apple's APIs to send an email and put the result into the body/subject as necessary, this would provide a much nicer user experience.

[See this answer for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087199/xcode-4-ios-send-an-email-using-smtp-from-inside-my-app)