# How can i send photo with email dont get mail screen

Tags: iphone, ios, sendmail, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Hi i all  i am trying send email with a photo. But i dont want see the screen
 [like this](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e2fbf214c6.gif)
 i want  when i pushed the button mail send automoticly.
my code:

```
MFMailComposeViewController * mailView = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mailView setMailComposeDelegate:self];  
[mailView setSubject:@"Subject"];
[mailView setToRecipients:self.selectedArray];
[self presentModalViewController:mailView animated:YES];
[mailView release];  

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {

    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You can not send email using MFMailComposeViewController in background.

Comment: Your 'like this' link doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is by implementing your own SMTP client in code.

See [Xcode 4 / iOS - Send an email using SMTP from inside my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087199/xcode-4-ios-send-an-email-using-smtp-from-inside-my-app) for more info.

Comment: Or by transferring the image to your web server and then emailing it from there.